# Using a .csv file to populate a ledger (.docx) of generated documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, docx, python-docx

I work in an educational institution and we need to keep track of all documents issued. Since we don't have databases, we are recording each document issued in a `word document`, which is then approved by the institution's system.

This is a example of how we store the data on the .csv file:

| name | email | document |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | john@gmail.com | 00x1 |
| maria | maria@gmail.com | 00x2 |

I am trying to automate the process with python. Currently I keep a `.csv` file with all the students' data, which is used both to create the documents and to register them in the book.

I need to think of a way to use this `.csv` file to automate the filling of records into a Word document. More specifically, I need to create a function that reads the information from each line of the CSV and fills the .docx file.

example:

```
N Reg: 1
name: john
email: john@gmail.com
document: 00x1

N Reg: 2
name: maria
email: maria@gmail.com
document: 00x2
```

Could someone kindly help me figure out where to start?

I have been trying to run some tests with pandas and python-docx, but I believe the insight of someone with more experience can help me

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/docxtpl/ can be used for creating the documents from templates. To read the csv file, python has built-in csv library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I processed the csv in `pandas` and wrote the output to docx with [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document

csv_data = '''name  email   document
john    john@gmail.com  00x1
maria   maria@gmail.com 00x2'''

# open csv in pandas; you can run df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), sep='\t')

# create an extra column that creates a string out of the other row items 
df['text'] = df.apply(lambda x: '\n'.join([f'N reg: {x.name+1}'] +  [f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in dict(x).items()]), axis=1) 

document = Document()
document.add_heading('Documents overview', 0) # add optional title

for i in df['text']:
    document.add_paragraph(i) # write each row to the document

document.save('docs.docx')
```